# How to return null if almost one inner join condition doesn't have value?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table called `league_ranking` which contains the ranking of a specific `round` for all the `teams` available within a `competition`.
Now happen that some `rounds` doesn't have any value in the `league_ranking` table, so in this case, I want to prevent that in the list of the `competitions` appear the `competition` that have almost a `round` without value in `league_ranking`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT c.name AS competition_name,
  c.id AS competition_id
  FROM competition c
  INNER JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.competition_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN league_ranking l ON l.round_id = r.id
  WHERE c.country_id = :country_id
  GROUP BY c.id
  ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

**Data example and table structure**

league_ranking

```
|position | team_id | round_id | 
     1        120        5
     2        124        5
```

competition_rounds

```
| id | season_id | name 
   5       577      First Round
   6       578      Preliminary Round
```

competition_seasons

```
|id | competition_id
 577      28
 578      28
```

competition

```
|id | name 
  28  Premier
```

as you can see the `round` 6 don't have values inside `league_ranking`, the problem is that my query even returns the competition `Premier`, how can I instead prevent to return this `competition` that have almost a `round` without value?

Thanks.

Comment: It's totally correct. Look at `competition_seasons`, both 2 seasons `577` and `578`  have `competition_id` = 28

Comment: @vnt yep the season must be different, the competition instead is the same with different rounds..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, You need to `Outer JOIN` base on `competition_rounds` table.

```
SELECT c.name AS competition_name,
c.id AS competition_id
FROM  competition_rounds r 
LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN competition c ON s.competition_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN league_ranking l ON l.round_id = r.id
WHERE c.country_id = :country_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Ht8nAHbtByX4muo8iZ3DW/1)

Comment: I already tried and I also get competition that doesn't have any rounds, so the situation gets worse

Comment: you can see sqlfiddle from my answer.

Comment: @jidic You need to Outer JOIN base on competition_rounds table

Comment: @jidic You can see my answer and SQL, It's `left join`

Comment: I saw your edit and I implemented your solution, but as I said I don't get the expected result that should return nothing because the competition have a round that doesn't have league_ranking..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174838/discussion-between-jidic-and-d-shih).

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data? @jidic